# Installing lidR package problems

Tags: r

I want to install lidR package and i faced with the below error problem. Can any one help me please?

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lidR’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘proxy’

Comment: Try `install.packages("proxy")`. If you get another " there is no package called " error, then try installing that package.

Comment: Also try `install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE)`. In fact `{proxy}` package is required by `{e1071}` package, which is required by `{classInt}` on which `{lidR}` is build.